# Xcode Saving NSMutableArray of String & BOOL values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I've got a little problem with an Application i am designing at the min but i'm a complete beginner, first of all a little information on what i am trying to accomplish.

I have a plist which populates an NSMutableArray which contains many values each one has a string and a BOOL inside, i can make the program save a copy of the file upon opening the app and load the data into the tableview along with an accessoryview of a checkmark.

now the checkmark works ok and you can select different items and the checkmark only appears on those items none of the others and if you inspect the log the details for each of the items check BOOL is changed but when i come to save a second time the checkmark state is not persisted for when i open the application a second time it just saves it as a 0 everytime.

here is some of my code, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Brad

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

 BOOL success;

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CustomChecklist.plist"];

 success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
 NSLog(@"STATUS OF SUCCESS %d",success);

 if (!success) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OriginalChecklist" ofType:@"plist"];
  success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:NULL];
  self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  NSLog(@"IF STATEMENT CREATING THE FILE");
 }else {
  self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  NSLog(@"IF STATEMENT READING THE FILE");
 }

 NSLog(@"location information %@", filePath);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID]  autorelease];
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
 }

 NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

 [item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

 BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
 UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
 button.frame = frame; // match the button's size with the image size

 [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.accessoryView = button;

  return cell;
 }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{  

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *savePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CustomChecklist.plist"];
 NSLog(@"View Will Disappear SAVE location information %@", savePath);
 [dataArray writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you change the value of the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` is not an object, it is a primitive type. Therefore, it cannot be saved (properly) in an array or dictionary. You need to use the `NSNumber` class to wrap it:

`[NSNumber numberWithBool:checked] //this should be added to the dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this from my phone, so I can't really see all of your code. But I just wanted to say that what you are trying to achieve can probably be solved by using NSUserdefaults instead of saving a file. Have you looked into that?

Oh, and just like Evan said, bool isn't an object. Only objects can be stored in an array.

Comment: how would you complete this using NSUserDefaults i think i have tried this but with no sucess again as i said i'm an absolute beginner. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are adding the cell to your dictionary? A UITableViewCell is not a property list compatible object, so it could keep your array from saving properly.